# Permutations with given longest increasing subsequence

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

How many permutations of 1 to 20 are there with 2,5,6,9,13
as a [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence)? (It may be tied with others.)

Comment: Can I ask (a general version of) this on Mathematics Stack Exchange (and link your puzzle)?

Comment: @BenjaminWang of course

Comment: Why the close votes?

Comment: I also don't understand the close votes. I am voting to keep this open!

Comment: Is there a reason to think there will be a nice solution here? Do you intend solvers to write code?

Comment: @xnor Nice needs a definition but I am happy for people to write code to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general idea:

> I think there would be many many such permutations and I am not sure how to count them all exactly. Let $S=\{2,5,6,9,13\}$. Any number that is not in $S$ can be placed anywhere such that it doesn't increase the length of the given subsequence. For example, 1 can be placed anywhere after 2. 3 and 4 can be placed before 2 or after 5. 7 and 8 can be placed before 6 or after 9, and so on. So for each number not in $S$ we need to count the number of "spots" where it can be placed. Also need to take into account their permutations within those spots.

I then wrote a Java computer [program](https://pastebin.com/UjVRUrrj)

> that tries to estimate the number of such permutations. It generates a random permutation and checks if (2, 5, 6, 9, 13) is one of its longest increasing subsequences (LIS). It uses dynamic programming to compute the LIS in $O(n^2)$ time. From a sample of 10000000 random permutations it found 1676 that meet the criteria, which is roughly 0.017%. This means that in the full set of 20! permutations we can expect about $4.1 \times 10^{14}$ permutations that meet the criteria.

Comment: If you have time, perhaps you'd like to check out the source pointed out in a comment under [my related Math SE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4771902/count-permutations-with-given-longest-increasing-subsequence)

Comment: Can you link to your code?

Comment: I've added a link to my code

Comment: Why not use the faster O(n log n) LIS algorithm?

Comment: I don't know it :) This runs sufficiently fast anyway